# Replace two quotes

Tags: java, regex

I cant find a solution to this simple problem.

I want to replace two consecutive '' or `` by ".

```
Input:
    some ``text'' dspsdj
Out: 
    some "text"
```

Why:

```
   s.replaceAll("[`{2}'{2}]", "\"")
Out:  
   some ""text""
```

???

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should do it like this:

```
s.replaceAll("``|''", "\"")
```

What you may have intended to do was this here:

```
s.replaceAll("[`']{2}", "\"")
```

But that wouldn't be entirely correct

Comment: Oh that's it, this is the same: "`{2}|'{2}". Thanks

Comment: @myro: Yes, that's the same. See also [juergen d](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10581012/521799)'s answer

Comment: Yeah, but you get the tick for being fastest :D

Answer (score 3):

```
String input = "some ``text'' dspsdj";
String output = input.replaceAll("`{2}|'{2}", "\"");
```

Answer (score 1):

Put the cardinality after the class:

```
.replaceAll("[`']{2}", "\""));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
String resultString = subjectString.replaceAll("([\"'`])\\1", "\"");
```

**Explanation:**

```
<!--
(["'`])\1

Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference number 1 «(["'`])»
   Match a single character present in the list “"'`” «["'`]»
Match the same text as most recently matched by capturing group number 1 «\1»
-->
```